# Querying XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am trying to query an xml document, but this code doesn't read xml parts with closed tag notation but reads fine  xelement.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

I have program generated XML document which gives closed tagged file hence its an issue now..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Student>

 <Person name="John" city="Auckland" country="NZ" />

 <Person>
    <Course>GDICT-CN</Course>
    <Level>7</Level>
    <Credit>120</Credit>
    <Date>129971035565221298</Date>
 </Person>
 <Person>
    <Course>GDICT-CN</Course>
    <Level>7</Level>
    <Credit>120</Credit>
    <Date>129971036040828501</Date>
 </Person>
</Student>
```

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Customers.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in xDoc.Descendants("Person") select row;

        foreach(XElement xEle in rows)
        {
        IEnumerable<XAttribute>attlist = from att in xEle.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes() select att;

            foreach(XAttribute xatt in attlist)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(xatt);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added `Course` and other attributes as `XElement`, so you need to loop on XElements instead of attributes -

```
foreach (XElement xEle in rows)
{
    IEnumerable<XAttribute> attlist = from att in xEle.DescendantsAndSelf()
                                        .Attributes() select att;

    foreach (XAttribute xatt in attlist)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(xatt);
    }
    foreach (XElement elemnt in xEle.Descendants())
    {
       Console.WriteLine(elemnt.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: That works like charm.. I am trying to understand what difference it made, could you just breif me if you don't mind.. Thank you.

Comment: `XAttribute` is for attributes whereas `XElement` is used for child Nodes. In the first row you have declared `name`, `city`and `country`as attributes. But in next two rows, you have created child Nodes that's why you need to loop over `Descendants`collection to get their values.

Comment: Thanks, and if I wanted to filter the values down I can't get the child element values using the below filter code, could you check that as well??? IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in xDoc.Descendants("Person")
                                         where (string)row.Attribute("Level") == "7"
                                         select row;

Comment: @raam030 you should refrain from asking follow up questions in comments.  If you are clarifying your existing question, then edit your question.  If you have a new question, you should ask a new question.  Sounds like you should be asking a new question as it is not really related to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

First you must navigate to Person level and iterate through Persons, then for each Person you can iterate through its attributes.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        //XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\Student Data\\data.xml");
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Customers.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = xDoc.Descendants("Person");
        foreach (XElement element in xElements)
        {
            foreach (XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(attribute);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```